# Wordpress: Button should be clicked automatically after page loaded

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, button

I'm using the Stripe payment gateway in my WordPress store. When you choose that payment option you will be redirected to another page and have to click a button there. This buttons opens an Iframe so the user can enter his credit car details. I want that button to be clicked automatically, so the Iframe opens after the page loaded.

Here's the HTML of that button:

2nd (noob) question: How can I change the style of that button with CSS? I tried targeting the class .wc-stripe-checkout-button but that didn't work...

Hope you can help :)

```
</li>
<li class="method">
    Payment method: <strong>Credit Card (Stripe)</strong>
</li>
</ul>

<form method="post" class="woocommerce-checkout" action="https://xxxxx.com/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Stripe/">
    <div id="stripe-payment-data" data-panel-label="" data-description="g" data-email="xxxxxxxxx" data-verify-zip="false" data-billing-address="false" data-shipping-address="false" data-amount="695" data-name="xxxxxxx" data-currency="eur" data-image="" data-locale="en" data-three-d-secure="true" data-allow-remember-me="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="78464" />
        <input type="hidden" name="stripe_checkout_order" value="yes" />
        <input type="hidden" id="stripe_checkout_process_nonce" name="stripe_checkout_process_nonce" value="e48208f479" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/checkout/order-pay/78464/?key=wc_order_Rj87dWBlEAIN3" />
        <button type="submit" class="wc-stripe-checkout-button">Place Order</button>    
    </form>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div></div></div>
</div>
```